# Playing RTSP stream in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp

I'm trying to play video stream on Android device. Unfortunatelly I still get the same problem with MediaPlayer/VideoView. I'm searching for a few days, but still haven't found any working solution.
For test purposes I'm using MediaPlayer app from API Demos (API Demos/Media/MediaPlayer/Play Streaming Video).
Here is code snippet for playing stream

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
```

When I try to play stream I get this info from logcat
http://pastebin.com/5Uib5CH5

This is configuration of ffserver streaming the video

```
Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0

RTSPPort 7654
RTSPBindAddress 0.0.0.0

MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 10000

CustomLog -
NoDaemon
&lt;Feed feed1.ffm&gt;

File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 5M

Launch ffmpeg -i mmsh://tempserv.cam/vid1

ACL allow 127.0.0.1

&lt;/Feed&gt;

&lt;Stream rat1.mpg&gt;
Feed feed1.ffm
Format rtp
NoAudio
VideoBitRate 56k
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoFrameRate 12
VideoSize 176x144
VideoGopSize 12
VideoCodec libx264
AVPresetVideo baseline
&lt;/Stream&gt;
```

If anyone can advise me how to fix it, or at least indicate an mistake, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution how to run streaming suitable for Android device. This is my ffserver configuration for any other person with the similar problem.

```
Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
RTSPPort 7654
RTSPBindAddress 0.0.0.0

MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 10000

CustomLog -
NoDaemon

<Feed feed1.ffm>

File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 5M

Launch ffmpeg -i mmsh://tempserv.cam/vid1

ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>

<Stream rat1.mpg>

Feed feed1.ffm
Format rtp
NoAudio

VideoBitRate 56k
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoFrameRate 12
VideoSize 176x144
VideoGopSize 12
VideoCodec h263

AVOptionVideo flags +global_header

</Stream>
```

Comment: In this case, yes. But ffmpeg is a kind of software which can work differently between two versions.